# How to split video into multiple files based on chapter markers?

Tags: video

Is there a way to automatically split a video into multiple files based on chapter markers?

I don't want to re-encode the file, just a video/audio passthru.

The source file is a MKV container, but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Apple OS X, Windows… either OS would be fine.

Comment: [Use ffmpeg to split file by chapters](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/469e2850e7f88ac198e8c3ff111bda7c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mkvmerge, a part of [MKVtoolnix](http://www.videohelp.com/software/MKVtoolnix), will split a MKV file by chapters.

Basic syntax is

```
mkvmerge -o chapter.mkv --split chapters:all input.mkv
```

but see [Section 2.5 #7](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.description) of the documentation for more details.